# RHEL / SELinux - Apache unable to write to a directory it can write to

Tags: files, permissions, rhel, apache-httpd, selinux

I have a RHEL 7 machine running an Apache web server with multiple virtual hosts on it. I've recently run into an issue where I am unable to upload media, e.g. images / pictures / video, to my machine for applications such as a blog (WordPress) and a forum (XenForo). I've tried to check out what's going on and I can't seem to figure it out.

Both applications seem to share the same root problem. I've double-checked that the file permissions should be correct, yet I still run into the same errors.

## Case 1

### WordPress: ../wp-content/

```
$ ls -Alh
total 8.0K
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jflory apache   28 Sep 26 09:50 index.php
drwxrwxr-x. 5 jflory apache   84 Oct 20 15:42 plugins
drwxrwxr-x. 7 jflory apache 4.0K Sep 26 12:07 themes
drwxr-xr-x. 2 jflory apache    6 Oct 20 15:42 upgrade
drwxrwxr--. 3 jflory apache   17 Sep 26 11:40 uploads
```

> “image.png” has failed to upload due to an error The uploaded file
>   could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2015/10.

## Case 2

### XenForo

```
$ ls -Alh ../public_html/
total 76K
drwxrwxrwx.  7 jflory apache   96 Oct 11 20:19 data
drwxrwxrwx.  6 jflory apache 4.0K Jul 19 02:57 internal_data
```

> The following errors occurred while verifying that your server can run
>   XenForo:
>
> The directory /var/www/crystalcraftmc.com/public_html/data must be writable. Please change the permissions on this directory to be world
>   writable (chmod 0777). If the directory does not exist, please create
>   it.
>
> The directory /var/www/crystalcraftmc.com/public_html/internal_data must be
>   writable. Please change the permissions on this directory to be world
>   writable (chmod 0777). If the directory does not exist, please create
>   it.
>
> Please correct these errors and try again.

I have double-checked that SELinux context is correct by running `sudo restorecon -Rv /var/www/`. This has worked in the past, but this time, it was not the solution. **HOWEVER**, I have tried disabling SELinux with `sudo setenforce 0`, restarted the Apache service, and this resolved the issue. It seems like SELinux is to blame, but I unsure as to why, and I don't wish to keep it disabled.

I am completely lost about what the issue can be - none of this makes sense. If any further information is needed, please ask me for clarification.